# Write a recursive function named get_first_capital(word) that takes a string as a parameter

Tags: python

Write a recursive function named get_first_capital(word) that takes a string as a parameter and returns the first capital letter that exists in a string using recursion. This function has to be recursive; you are not allowed to use loops to solve this problem.

```
def get_first_capital(word):
    if word[0].isupper():
        return word[0] + get_first_capital(word[1:])
    else:
        return None

print(get_first_capital('helLo'))

except:

print(get_first_capital('helLo'))
```

Comment: OK but what is your problem?

Comment: I cannot get the first capital letter when I run my code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the first character if it's uppercase; otherwise you should return what the recursive call returns with the rest of the characters, until there is no more character in the string:

```
def get_first_capital(word):
    return word and (word[0] if word[0].isupper() else get_first_capital(word[1:]))
```

so that `get_first_capital('helLo')` returns: `'L'`

Answer (score 0):

In order to tackle recursive functions, you first need to think about their base cases. Base cases are those that would not allow the function to continue forward.

In this case, we would want to check if the string is null, or empty. When we find a null, or empty string we need to return the base case, which could be an empty string itself or a warning stating that there was no capital letters found.

Another case to check for is if the letter itself is capital. If it is capital, then return that letter.

Lastly, if we've still got work to do (meaning there are more characters to check) then we just have to call the function again with the string starting with the next unchecked character.

```
def get_first_capital(word):
    if word == "":
        return "Nothing Found"
    elif word[0].isupper():
        return word[0]
    else:
        return get_first_capital(word[1:])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_first_capital("Hello"))
    print(get_first_capital("hello"))
```